# Force a page to be rendered in admin theme

Tags: theming, 8

In drupal 7 we could force a page to open in admin page, there are several way to do that in drupal 7

- with [hook_admin_paths](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7.x)

  function hook_admin_paths() {
    $paths = array(
      'mymodule/*/add' => TRUE,
      'mymodule/*/edit' => TRUE,
    );
    return $paths;
  }
- with [Admin theme module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_theme)
- with [ThemeKeys module](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

Now I am looking for equivalent solution in Drupal 8, **How can I force drupal to render a specified pages as admin theme?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the _admin_route option to a route:

```
aggregator.feed_add:
  path: '/aggregator/sources/add'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\aggregator\Controller\AggregatorController::feedAdd'
    _title: 'Add feed'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer news feeds'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

You can also implement your own negotiator (See \Drupal\user\Theme\AdminNegotiator) or add that option to routes dynamically in a request subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for your attentions, it seems you answer is right, I have a custom content type, lets call him "course" , I want when user try to see ( I mean view the course node), it'll opened by admin theme?,can you help me about this case?

Comment: can you tell me how? I still waiting for your answer